# ListedColormap for identifying grid squares in matplotlib.pyplot.grid in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

How to reference or identify specific grid squares in a grid created using matplotlib.pyplot in python? I've used ListedColorMap to do this but I don't understand how to change the grid squares color to different colors and how ListedColormaps work?

Here is my code :

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import itertools


N = 15
# making an empty data set
data = np.ones((N, N)) 


fig = plt.figure()              # creates the figure
ax = fig.gca() 


# fill in some sample data
data[6] = 1


# make color map
my_cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['g', 'b'])


ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-10, 0, 1))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-10, 0, 1))


for t in range(N + 1):
   ax.axhline(t, lw=2, color='k', zorder=5)
   ax.axvline(t, lw=2, color='k', zorder=5)

# draw the boxes
ax.imshow(data, interpolation='none', cmap=my_cmap, extent=[0, N, 0, N], 
zorder=0)
# turn off the axis labels
ax.axis('on')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Your data necessarily needs to have *different* values for two or more colors to be shown. Currently you have only `1`s, so they all have the same color. Use e.g. `data[6] = 2` to see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a color for some specific squares on the grid, first you need to make sure that the `data` for those locations are **different** from the others. For example, if you'd like the color the **first row first two columns** and **second row first two columns**, you'd do the following:

```py
# Your data variable starts of having 1's at every location.
# To be able to see different colors, change the data
# at those locations. Here we set the data to 2. It could be
# any number different from 1.
data[0][0] = 2
data[0][1] = 2
data[1][0] = 2
data[1][1] = 2
```

The above helps you change colors for specific squares on the grid.

If you'd like to specify the colors that your grid's display, you have to specify them in the *colors* argument in `matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors, name='from_list', N=None)`.

```py
# In this case, 'w' or white will be used for all the 1's in data.
# 'b' or blue will be used for all the 2's and 'r' or red for all the 3's.
# If you want to add new data, you can make it use new colors by adding
# more colors to the colors list.
# If you add new data but not new colors, the last color will be selected
# for the new data. 
my_cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['w', 'b', 'r'])
```

Reference: [ListedColorMap](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html)

Reference: [colors - Matplotlib](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Matplotlib/api/colors_api.html)